# Linear independence "modulo $\mathbb Z^n$"

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $M \in \{0,1\}^{n{\times}m}$ be a $n{\times}m$-matrix $(m \leq n)$ with entries in $\{0,1\}$ whose column vectors are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$. 
This means that, for any $x \in \mathbb R^m$, $Mx=0$ implies $x=0$.

My question is, does under these conditions also $Mx \in \mathbb Z^n$ imply $x \in \mathbb Z^m$? Proof/counterexample? More generally, if instead $Mx$ is "close" to  $\mathbb Z^n$ in some suitable metric, does it follow that $x$ is "close" to  $Z^m$?

**Edit:**
Clive has produced a simple counterexample showing that the answer to my question above is "no". 
Let me therefore slightly modify the question. 
Assume that the entries of $M$ are all in $\{-1,1\}$ instead; 
does $\frac12 Mx \in \mathbb Z^n$ now imply $x \in \mathbb Z^m$?

Comment: See however the topic of [unimodular matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix), for which an integer solution vector $x$ will always result from integer vector $Mx$.

Comment: Thanks, but that class is too special for my purposes.

Comment: While it is an understandable temptation, avoid changing the Question in ways that make it subtly incompatible with the original problem, esp. once that original problem has been satisfactorily answered.  If you cannot solve the new problem for yourself after a reasonable amount of effort, then perhaps the best approach is to post a new Question (linking to the old one for context as necessary).

Comment: @hardmath - You are right, it is a subtly different question, albeit no ad hoc modification but the one I actually had been studying in the first place. Unfortunately I had tried to simplify it here into a "cleaner" problem with similar properties, wich turned out to be deceptive.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your first question is 'no', for example
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 \\ 1/2 \\ -1/2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
As for your second question, I suspect the answer is also 'no', but it's not really clear what you mean. You can cook up metrics to make things arbitrarily close to other things, but that doesn't necessarily give you useful information. I think $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},{-\frac{1}{2}})$ is about as far from $\mathbb{Z}^3$ as you can reasonably expect to be, though!

Comment: Thanks a lot Clive, for some reason I overlooked this very simple counterexample. My second question was intended as a generalization of the first and does not make much sense anymore now.

Comment: In an edit I have added a modification of my question (which is actually closer to the problem I had originally in mind). Can you find a counterexample also in this version?

Comment: @DierkBormann: In that case, there is an even simpler counterexample: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 \\ 1/2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Clive, please note that I included an additional factor $\frac12$ on $Mx$ here since the difference between $-1$ and $1$ is $2$. Otherwise the statement would indeed be trivially wrong.

Comment: @DierkBormann: Still no, for example $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&-1 \\ 1&1&-1&1 \\ 1&-1&1&1 \\ -1&1&1&1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1/4 \\ 1/4 \\ 1/4 \\ -1/4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks Clive, I really appreciate your help. It seems I had sort of a mind block here :)